# mongoose listCollections() not returning collections name instead return a promise pending

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create model on the fly so I am using below code for achieving same.

```
var connection = mongoose.createConnection(metadb_uri, mongo_opts, function() {
   log.debug(process.env.DB_ENV+' setup done')
});

const _schema = new Schema({
   count:Number,
   users:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, default: {}} 
});

let name = 'name_123';

//trying to get collection names
connection.db.listCollections.toArray().then((names) => {

    if (!(name in names.name)) {
       let userAnalyticsDB = connection.model(name,_schema);
       module.exports.Collection = userAnalyticsDB;
    }
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
    return err;
  })
});
```

so connection.db.listCollections.toArray() returns promise state as pending. 
Can anyone have an idea , why it is giving promise value as `undefined`.

Please give me some hint.

Comment: Have you tried actually calling the method: `connection.db.listCollections().toArray().then(callback)`?

Comment: @chridam I added callback as well but as soon as it reaches to `connection.db.listCollections()` object it jumb up and call next function and went inside of the function.

Comment: # and  it's not going inside of the `listCollections()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers and help. 
I debug the issue and found that it was related to Promise hell.
I wrote promise within promise. so it was returning promise as `pending` and `undefined`